# It rcording but recorded video is not playin.it gives the error "moov data not found",plese help me to solve this

Tags: c, linux, video, gstreamer, webcam

I am working on gstreamer. I need to capture the video from a web cam and store as a specific .mp4 file. For this I developed an application, it works fine for capturing recording and playing. But if I press the ctrl+c signal, it records but the recorded video does not play. It gives the error "moov data not found". I searched that error in google. I got the what is the problem but I don't know how to solve it. please help me to solve this

Comment: Perhaps it would be nice if you shared the problem?

Comment: Tell us what you searched and what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

MP4 files or not be introupted while recording. They need need to be cleanly closed (ie write the moov box). Eaither shut down the stream cleanly (not cancel via ctrl c) or use a streamable format like flv, and remix to MP4 as a post processing step.